# Understanding the conditions to define derivatives of composition of functions?

Tags: calculus, functions

$ \Delta y=\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}} \Delta x + k \Delta x$

Where k is a correction variable factor that depends on $ x_{1} $ and $ \Delta x$. Once $x_{1} $ is chosen and fixed k will depend on $  \Delta x $ only.

$ \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} k=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}})=0$

Suppose y = f(x) and x = g(t). Let y and x be differentiable at $x_{1}$ and $t_{1}$, respectively. Find $ \frac{dy}{dt}$.For the composition y = f(g(t)) to make sense, the co-domain of g, which is x, must either be equal to the domain of f or be a subset of it.

From the above
(1) $ \Delta y=\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}} \Delta x + k_{1} \Delta x$

(2) $ \Delta x=\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=t_{1}} \Delta t + k_{2} \Delta t$

Re-arranging (2) we obtain:

$ \Delta t=\frac{\Delta x}{\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=t_{1}} + k_{2}}$

For all points x in the interval $ [ x_{1}, x_{1} + \Delta x ] $, x must belong to the domain of f.For any $ \Delta t >0 \hspace{0.1cm} \Delta x \neq 0$.Are these the only conditions that must be satisfied to ensure the composition is defined and to imply the differentiability of f as a function of t from the assumption of the differentiability of f as a function of x and x as a function of t?

$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}= \Delta x(\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}} +k_{1}) \frac{1}{\Delta x}({\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=t_{1}} + k_{2}})$

$ \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}=\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} (\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}} +k_{1})({\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=t_{1}} + k_{2}})= \frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_{1}}\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=t_{1}} $
Why is the LHS limit  equal to $ \frac{dy}{dt} $? Is it because as $ \Delta t \rightarrow 0 $ $ \Delta x \rightarrow 0 $ which in turn makes $ \Delta y \rightarrow 0 $?

Where

$ \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} k_{1}= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} k_{2}=0 $

Comment: When asking about differentiability, you suddenly start talking about $f$. But none of your discussion leading up to this defined any $f$. Instead it involves only two functions $y(x)$ and $x(t)$, and their composition $y(x(t))$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I did not specify any "f" to generalize and to draw conclusions from the assumptions. Starting with two functions: y = f(x) and x = g(t), where "f" and "g" are rules that map "x" onto "y" and "x" and "t" onto "x," certain restrictions need to be made to define the composition function. To determine its differentiability, I was asking if for any $ \Delta t $ $ \Delta x \neq 0 $ and every x in $ [x, x+ \Delta x] $ must belong to the domain of f implies the differentiability of the composition function.